# How to design multi-objectives A*star algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

How to design multi-objectives A*star algorithm? and what is the  main idea of Multi-objective A*, For assignment problem one objective is minimize the cost and second objective is maximize the profit?please explain with example.

Comment: Could you please copy paste your assignment problem, it's a bit hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: asking for a complete solution to a problem is a bit off. Its better if you ask where the problem is exactly.

Comment: i have problem how to calculate h function in Multi-objective A*star algorithm is there any rule to calculate h function please give me some example how can i calculate heuristic h function?